# Capture embedded google map image with Python without using a browser

Tags: python, google-maps, image-stitching

I have noticed that, from Google Maps page, you can get an "embed" link to put inside an iframe and load the map in a browser. (no news here)

The image size can be adjusted to be very large, so I am interested in getting som big images as single .PNGs.

More specifically, I would like to define a rectangular area from a bounding box (upper-right and lower-left coordinates), and get the corresponding image, with an appropriate zoom factor.

But my question is: How can I use Python to get the "pixel content" of this map as an image object?

(My rationale is: if the browser can get and render such image content, then Python should be capable of doing it, too).

EDIT: this is the content of the HTML file that shows my sample map:

```
<iframe 
    width="2000"
    height="1500"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="yes"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="http://maps.google.com.br/maps?hl=pt-BR&amp;ll=-30.027489,-51.229248&amp;spn=1.783415,2.745209&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed"/>
```

EDIT: I did as suggested by Ned Batchelder, and read the content of an `urllib.urlopen()` call using the `src` address taken from the iframe above. The result was a lot of javascript code, which I think has to do with the Google Maps JavaScript API. So, the question lingers: how could I do some useful stuff from all this stuff in Python in order to get the map image?

EDIT: this link appears to contain some pretty relevant info on how Google Maps tiles their maps:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scrapbook/googlemap.aspx

also:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/howitworks.htm

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I thank for all the answers. I ended up solving the problem another way, using Google Maps Static API and some formulas to convert from Coordinate space to Pixel space, so that I can get precise images that "stitch" nicely together.

For anyone interested, here is the code. If it helps someone, please comment!

=============================

```
import Image, urllib, StringIO
from math import log, exp, tan, atan, pi, ceil

EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137
EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * pi * EARTH_RADIUS
INITIAL_RESOLUTION = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 256.0
ORIGIN_SHIFT = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 2.0

def latlontopixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = (lon * ORIGIN_SHIFT) / 180.0
    my = log(tan((90 + lat) * pi/360.0))/(pi/180.0)
    my = (my * ORIGIN_SHIFT) /180.0
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    px = (mx + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    py = (my + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    return px, py

def pixelstolatlon(px, py, zoom):
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    mx = px * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    my = py * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    lat = (my / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    lat = 180 / pi * (2*atan(exp(lat*pi/180.0)) - pi/2.0)
    lon = (mx / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    return lat, lon

############################################

# a neighbourhood in Lajeado, Brazil:

upperleft =  '-29.44,-52.0'  
lowerright = '-29.45,-51.98'

zoom = 18   # be careful not to get too many images!

############################################

ullat, ullon = map(float, upperleft.split(','))
lrlat, lrlon = map(float, lowerright.split(','))

# Set some important parameters
scale = 1
maxsize = 640

# convert all these coordinates to pixels
ulx, uly = latlontopixels(ullat, ullon, zoom)
lrx, lry = latlontopixels(lrlat, lrlon, zoom)

# calculate total pixel dimensions of final image
dx, dy = lrx - ulx, uly - lry

# calculate rows and columns
cols, rows = int(ceil(dx/maxsize)), int(ceil(dy/maxsize))

# calculate pixel dimensions of each small image
bottom = 120
largura = int(ceil(dx/cols))
altura = int(ceil(dy/rows))
alturaplus = altura + bottom


final = Image.new("RGB", (int(dx), int(dy)))
for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        dxn = largura * (0.5 + x)
        dyn = altura * (0.5 + y)
        latn, lonn = pixelstolatlon(ulx + dxn, uly - dyn - bottom/2, zoom)
        position = ','.join((str(latn), str(lonn)))
        print x, y, position
        urlparams = urllib.urlencode({'center': position,
                                      'zoom': str(zoom),
                                      'size': '%dx%d' % (largura, alturaplus),
                                      'maptype': 'satellite',
                                      'sensor': 'false',
                                      'scale': scale})
        url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?' + urlparams
        f=urllib.urlopen(url)
        im=Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(f.read()))
        final.paste(im, (int(x*largura), int(y*altura)))
final.show()
```

Comment: Very nice! I got it to work but needed to make a few small changes as here: https://gist.github.com/BenElgar/0d5b3e7cc89cb2180c6e. Note that this is Python 2 but it shouldn't be too hard to get it to work in Python 3. Also be aware that this is technically breaking the terms of use for the static maps API as detailed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3

Comment: Wow, those maths are hideous!! See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536888/1840698

Comment: BUG: you should do "maxsize -= bottom" before using it, otherwise "alturaplus" will exceed the limit of 640 pixels and the API will crop the image. More specifically, in order to fix it simply delete the line "bottom = 120" and insert the lines "bottom = 120" and "maxsize -= bottom" below the line "maxsize = 640". Also might wanna rename "largura" and "altura" to "width" and "height", respectively.

Answer (score 16):

Rather than trying to use the embed link, you should go directly to the Google API to get images as static graphics. Here's the link to the [Google Maps static image API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) - it looks like you can just pass in the long/lat parameters in the URL just as you do for the normal embeddable one. For example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=600x600&zoom=14&sensor=false
```

gives you an 600x600 street-level overview centered on the co-ordinates you give above, which seems to be Porto Alegre in Brazil. Now you can use `urlopen` and `PIL` as Ned suggests:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import Image
import urllib

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=800x800&zoom=14&sensor=false"
buffer = StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
image = Image.open(buffer)
```

Comment: That is my alternative for now, but I still want to try to make it "Plan B", since image stitching would be necessary to generate those megapixel-sized images I am aiming for. Getting coordinates for image corners is not necessarily easy or obvious, and since the embedded maps stitch together automagically, perhaps to study the javascript api could give some insight. Thanks for your tips and for your nice code snippet!

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**:
the code in this answer has been improved and simplified, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536888/5859283

---

Based on the excellent answer from heltonbiker with changes from BenElgar, below is some updated code for Python 3 and the addition of API key access, hope its useful for somebody:

```
"""
Stitch together Google Maps images from lat, long coordinates
Based on work by heltonbiker and BenElgar
Changes: 
  * updated for Python 3
  * added Google Cloud Static Maps API key field (now required for access)
  * handle http request exceptions
"""

import requests
from io import BytesIO
from math import log, exp, tan, atan, pi, ceil
from PIL import Image
import sys

EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137
EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * pi * EARTH_RADIUS
INITIAL_RESOLUTION = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 256.0
ORIGIN_SHIFT = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 2.0
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'change this to your API key'

def latlontopixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = (lon * ORIGIN_SHIFT) / 180.0
    my = log(tan((90 + lat) * pi/360.0))/(pi/180.0)
    my = (my * ORIGIN_SHIFT) /180.0
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    px = (mx + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    py = (my + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    return px, py

def pixelstolatlon(px, py, zoom):
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    mx = px * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    my = py * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    lat = (my / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    lat = 180 / pi * (2*atan(exp(lat*pi/180.0)) - pi/2.0)
    lon = (mx / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    return lat, lon


def get_maps_image(NW_lat_long, SE_lat_long, zoom=18):
  
  ullat, ullon = NW_lat_long
  lrlat, lrlon = SE_lat_long
  
  # Set some important parameters
  scale = 1
  maxsize = 640
  
  # convert all these coordinates to pixels
  ulx, uly = latlontopixels(ullat, ullon, zoom)
  lrx, lry = latlontopixels(lrlat, lrlon, zoom)
  
  # calculate total pixel dimensions of final image
  dx, dy = lrx - ulx, uly - lry
  
  # calculate rows and columns
  cols, rows = int(ceil(dx/maxsize)), int(ceil(dy/maxsize))
  
  # calculate pixel dimensions of each small image
  bottom = 120
  largura = int(ceil(dx/cols))
  altura = int(ceil(dy/rows))
  alturaplus = altura + bottom
  
  # assemble the image from stitched
  final = Image.new("RGB", (int(dx), int(dy)))
  for x in range(cols):
      for y in range(rows):
          dxn = largura * (0.5 + x)
          dyn = altura * (0.5 + y)
          latn, lonn = pixelstolatlon(ulx + dxn, uly - dyn - bottom/2, zoom)
          position = ','.join((str(latn), str(lonn)))
          print(x, y, position)
          urlparams = {'center': position,
                        'zoom': str(zoom),
                        'size': '%dx%d' % (largura, alturaplus),
                        'maptype': 'satellite',
                        'sensor': 'false',
                        'scale': scale}
          if GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY is not None:
            urlparams['key'] = GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
            
          url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap'
          try:                  
            response = requests.get(url, params=urlparams)
            response.raise_for_status()
          except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(1)
            
          im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))                  
          final.paste(im, (int(x*largura), int(y*altura)))
          
  return final

############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  
  # a neighbourhood in Lajeado, Brazil:
  NW_lat_long =  (-29.44,-52.0)
  SE_lat_long = (-29.45,-51.98)
  
  zoom = 18   # be careful not to get too many images!
  
  result = get_maps_image(NW_lat_long, SE_lat_long, zoom=18)
  result.show()
```

Comment: Using this again a year later, an API key is now compulsory for access. A Google Cloud account and a key for the Maps Static API is what you need

Answer (score 8):

@4Oh4's answer is right, but the maths are more complicated than they need to be. Conversions between degrees and radians happen more often than they need to. The Earth's radius is invoked for no reason—it cancels in all calculations. An offset is added to the pixel coordinates for no reason. The logo cutoff is bigger than it needs to be. And a few other odds and ends, which have been written in the changes. Here's my version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Stitch together Google Maps images from lat, long coordinates
Based on work by heltonbiker and BenElgar
Changes: 
* updated for Python 3
* added Google Maps API key (compliance with T&C, although can set to None)
* handle http request exceptions

With contributions from Eric Toombs.
Changes:
* Dramatically simplified the maths.
* Set a more reasonable default logo cutoff.
* Added global constants for logo cutoff and max image size.
* Translated a couple presumably Portuguese variable names to English.
"""

import requests
from io import BytesIO
from math import log, exp, tan, atan, ceil
from PIL import Image
import sys

# circumference/radius
tau = 6.283185307179586
# One degree in radians, i.e. in the units the machine uses to store angle,
# which is always radians. For converting to and from degrees. See code for
# usage demonstration.
DEGREE = tau/360

ZOOM_OFFSET = 8
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = None  # set to 'your_API_key'

# Max width or height of a single image grabbed from Google.
MAXSIZE = 640
# For cutting off the logos at the bottom of each of the grabbed images.  The
# logo height in pixels is assumed to be less than this amount.
LOGO_CUTOFF = 32


def latlon2pixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = lon
    my = log(tan((lat + tau/4)/2))
    res = 2**(zoom + ZOOM_OFFSET) / tau
    px = mx*res
    py = my*res
    return px, py

def pixels2latlon(px, py, zoom):
    res = 2**(zoom + ZOOM_OFFSET) / tau
    mx = px/res
    my = py/res
    lon = mx
    lat = 2*atan(exp(my)) - tau/4
    return lat, lon


def get_maps_image(NW_lat_long, SE_lat_long, zoom=18):

    ullat, ullon = NW_lat_long
    lrlat, lrlon = SE_lat_long

    # convert all these coordinates to pixels
    ulx, uly = latlon2pixels(ullat, ullon, zoom)
    lrx, lry = latlon2pixels(lrlat, lrlon, zoom)

    # calculate total pixel dimensions of final image
    dx, dy = lrx - ulx, uly - lry

    # calculate rows and columns
    cols, rows = ceil(dx/MAXSIZE), ceil(dy/MAXSIZE)

    # calculate pixel dimensions of each small image
    width = ceil(dx/cols)
    height = ceil(dy/rows)
    heightplus = height + LOGO_CUTOFF

    # assemble the image from stitched
    final = Image.new('RGB', (int(dx), int(dy)))
    for x in range(cols):
        for y in range(rows):
            dxn = width * (0.5 + x)
            dyn = height * (0.5 + y)
            latn, lonn = pixels2latlon(
                    ulx + dxn, uly - dyn - LOGO_CUTOFF/2, zoom)
            position = ','.join((str(latn/DEGREE), str(lonn/DEGREE)))
            print(x, y, position)
            urlparams = {
                    'center': position,
                    'zoom': str(zoom),
                    'size': '%dx%d' % (width, heightplus),
                    'maptype': 'satellite',
                    'sensor': 'false',
                    'scale': 1
                }
            if GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY is not None:
                urlparams['key'] = GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY

            url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap'
            try:                  
                response = requests.get(url, params=urlparams)
                response.raise_for_status()
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(e)
                sys.exit(1)

            im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))                  
            final.paste(im, (int(x*width), int(y*height)))

    return final

############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # a neighbourhood in Lajeado, Brazil:
    NW_lat_long =  (-29.44*DEGREE, -52.0*DEGREE)
    SE_lat_long = (-29.45*DEGREE, -51.98*DEGREE)

    result = get_maps_image(
        NW_lat_long,
        SE_lat_long,
        zoom=18 # be careful not to get too many images!
    )
    result.show()
```

Comment: That is a bit more straightforward!

Comment: Hi, How can I add lines and pins to the map generated? I have asked that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56555592/adding-lines-and-pins-to-map-image

Comment: Using this again a year later, an API key is now compulsory for access. A Google Cloud account and a key for the Maps Static API is what you need

Comment: `zoom = 18   # be careful not to get too many images!`. You're not using this variable.

Answer (score 6):

This is [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7491390/2506817) for people that use python 3.x:

- Assuming you got already [Google Maps static image API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Python 3.x code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from urllib import request
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # this is if you want to plot the map using pyplot

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-30.027489,-51.229248&size=800x800&zoom=14&sensor=false"

buffer = BytesIO(request.urlopen(url).read())
image = Image.open(buffer)

# Show Using PIL
image.show()

# Or using pyplot
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: BUG: you should do "maxsize -= bottom" before using it, otherwise "alturaplus" will exceed the limit of 640 pixels and the API will crop the image. More specifically, in order to fix it simply delete the line "bottom = 120" and insert the lines "bottom = 120" and "maxsize -= bottom" below the line "maxsize = 640". Also might wanna rename "largura" and "altura" to "width" and "height", respectively.

Answer (score 3):

A more concise Python 2.x compatible method is

```
from io import BytesIO
import Image
import urllib

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=52.50058,13.31316&size=800x800&zoom=14"
buffer = BytesIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
image = Image.open(buffer)
image.save("map.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest way to have the Google static map image captured/saved (as a png):

```
import requests

img = open('tmp.png','wb')
img.write(requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=33.0456,131.3009&zoom=12&size=320x385&key=YOUR_API_KEY').content)
img.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.urlopen` will open a URL, the result will have a `.read()` method you can use to get the image bytes.  `cStringIO` has a file-like object based on a string in memory.  PIL has an `Image.open` function that opens a file-like thing to give you an image object.  Image objects can be asked about their pixel values.

Comment: Using urllib as you said gives me javascript code (I think), not an image object. It makes sense, since the embedded map allows navigation (it is not generated using Google Maps Static API, which itself has some serious limits on image size).

Comment: @heltonbiker: sorry, I don't know how to help with the more complex problem.  The original description sounded more straightforward.

Comment: I am very thankful for your insights and interest. Actually, I use your suggestion with Google Maps Static API. The problem asked, although, perhaps is more easily solved using some javascript directly. If I find a good answer, I'll post it here. Thanks again!