# Plot google maps data as a picture without generating an html file

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm using the python library gmplot for getting a map from GoogleMaps and georeferencing some point coordinates. I would like to plot my Googlemap result in a detached window like I do with images generated with matplotlib, but with gmplot I can see only the draw() function which generates an html of the googlemaps code. Now I'm using the following functions:

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(lat[0],lon[0],18)
gmap.scatter(lat,lon, 'r', 0.1, marker=False)
gmap.draw('map.html')
```

Should I use another python library or can I generate an image with gmplot?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a map as an image you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490491/capture-embedded-google-map-image-with-python-without-using-a-browser) to do that. With some minor change i was able to get the result in a .bmp format.

here is my small edited code for reference

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib, StringIO
from math import log, exp, tan, atan, pi, ceil

EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137
EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * pi * EARTH_RADIUS
INITIAL_RESOLUTION = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 256.0
ORIGIN_SHIFT = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 2.0

def latlontopixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = (lon * ORIGIN_SHIFT) / 180.0
    my = log(tan((90 + lat) * pi/360.0))/(pi/180.0)
    my = (my * ORIGIN_SHIFT) /180.0
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    px = (mx + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    py = (my + ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    return px, py

def pixelstolatlon(px, py, zoom):
    res = INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    mx = px * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    my = py * res - ORIGIN_SHIFT
    lat = (my / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    lat = 180 / pi * (2*atan(exp(lat*pi/180.0)) - pi/2.0)
    lon = (mx / ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    return lat, lon

############################################

upperleft =  '-29.44,-52.0'  
lowerright = '-29.45,-51.98'

zoom = 18   # be careful not to get too many images!

ullat, ullon = map(float, upperleft.split(','))
lrlat, lrlon = map(float, lowerright.split(','))
scale = 1
maxsize = 640
ulx, uly = latlontopixels(ullat, ullon, zoom)
lrx, lry = latlontopixels(lrlat, lrlon, zoom)
dx, dy = lrx - ulx, uly - lry
cols, rows = int(ceil(dx/maxsize)), int(ceil(dy/maxsize))
bottom = 120
largura = int(ceil(dx/cols))
altura = int(ceil(dy/rows))
alturaplus = altura + bottom


final = Image.new("RGB", (int(dx), int(dy)))
for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        dxn = largura * (0.5 + x)
        dyn = altura * (0.5 + y)
        latn, lonn = pixelstolatlon(ulx + dxn, uly - dyn - bottom/2, zoom)
        position = ','.join((str(latn), str(lonn)))
        print x, y, position
        urlparams = urllib.urlencode({'center': position,
                                      'zoom': str(zoom),
                                      'size': '%dx%d' % (largura, alturaplus),
                                      'maptype': 'satellite',
                                      'sensor': 'false',
                                      'scale': scale})
        url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?' + urlparams
        f=urllib.urlopen(url)
        im=Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(f.read()))
        final.paste(im, (int(x*largura), int(y*altura)))
final.show()
```

and yes to run the above code you will require [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.0.0) module.

hope it may help !

Answer (score 1):

This would also work: First download [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) to your hard drive (e.g. to C:\chromedriver.exe) and `pip install selenium`.

Then use this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(r"C:\route.html")
time.sleep(3)      
driver.save_screenshot('map.png')
driver.quit()
```