# How can I fetch high-resolution google map satellite image using Python?

Tags: python, google-maps, resolution, satellite

I am using Google map to capture satellite images using Python.
 I followed the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490491/capture-embedded-google-map-image-with-python-without-using-a-browser. However, compared to the  view directly from browser, the images from Python have lower resolution.

For example, at a certain location, what I fetched from Python looks like 
[image]

But the view of the same location from browser has much higher resolution (though not at the exactly same zoom range):

[image]

The Google map API has parameters as follows:

```
'center': position, 
'zoom': str(zoom),
'size': '%dx%d' % (largura, alturaplus),
'maptype': 'satellite',
'sensor': 'false',
'scale': scale
```

Is there parameter to tune the resolution?
  A ton of thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the imagery scraping might be against the Terms of Service of Google Maps APIs.

Particularly section 10.1 (a) says

> **No access to APIs or Content except through the Service**. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

section 10.5 (d) says

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage)

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#10-license-restrictions