# Getting 403 client foridden error on google maps even after entering api key

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490491/capture-embedded-google-map-image-with-python-without-using-a-browser/50536888#50536888) with a google maps static api key(  ) added at line 31.
The Key is unrestricted, & I can even see error "403" on api dashboard.
Why I'm getting error 403 even after entering key?

[image: dashboard]

I was able to get images using API key only till few ours back,
here's the screenshot

[image]

I even tried this with different project & keys like
[google web tool to signed url](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/apis/static-maps-backend.googleapis.com/staticmap?project=show-map-1540306832731&duration=PT6H)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Based on [Maps Static API - Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/error-messages), getting 403 Forbidden means the API key included in the request is invalid. Please check thoroughly with the [Get API Key and Signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key) and Dashboard that you are generating and using the correct API key.

Comment: can't I use api via unsigned usage?

Comment: quoted from the page "Requests to the Maps Static API should include a signature parameter, containing a digital signature which you must generate using a shared URL signing secret. Your shared secret is available on the Google Cloud Platform Console."

Comment: & this code I mentioned ,can have varying parameters(latitude & longitude) ,making a signed url won't limit to map of only one location?

Comment: You can make multiple different request using the same key and signature. However, each API has their own limits to the number of requests that can be made

Comment: it isn't working , is there any way to access map just with API key?

Comment: You can use [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), which only requires API key. Otherwise, simply set up the signature following the guides

Comment: I have been making my programs with key only without any digital signature,& it was working till few hours back

Comment: Then check what changes in the last few hours and see how it can be resolved or add that to the question

Comment: tried javascript ,didn't worked, anyway url for javascript is different from static maps

Comment: Yes it is different, since it is a different API. I would suggest for you to trace back the changes between the last time it works and now, to see what is wrong with the code

Comment: I have been using just API key with static map url ,I can't figure out how, Is there a way possible?

Comment: Quoted from the page: "You should set up and use a digital signature in all requests. Requests without a signature might fail.". However, it never explains why it might fail

Comment: Do you receive any specific error message than simply 403 Forbidden? And may I know why you are not able to generate and use signature along with API key? Since its usage is recommended by the documentation itself

Comment: Because I'm unable to generate the signtaure,https://github.com/googlemaps/url-signing/blob/gh-pages/urlsigner.py I tried this code , getting error in urlparse,which is another issue

Comment: That is not the only way to generate the signature. You can check various other ways in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#dig-sig-key)

Comment: added a screenshot

Comment: You might want to censor your API key over there. And also, try to generate your signature on the guide page linked above, and use it in your request. Also, you can try opening that request url in a web browser, to see if there is any other error messages included.

Comment: I have already deleted that key,btw I tried key & signature combination,can u create ur own key & signature check to see if it's working?