# Adding lines and pins to map image

Tags: python, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple routes and pins to a map and export that as  an image and not a HTML. I found @enigmaticPhysicist [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536888/11634796) with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Stitch together Google Maps images from lat, long coordinates
Based on work by heltonbiker and BenElgar
Changes:
* updated for Python 3
* added Google Maps API key (compliance with T&C, although can set to None)
* handle http request exceptions

With contributions from Eric Toombs.
Changes:
* Dramatically simplified the maths.
* Set a more reasonable default logo cutoff.
* Added global constants for logo cutoff and max image size.
* Translated a couple presumably Portuguese variable names to English.
"""

import requests
from io import BytesIO
from math import log, exp, tan, atan, ceil
from PIL import Image
import sys

# circumference/radius
tau = 6.283185307179586
# One degree in radians, i.e. in the units the machine uses to store angle,
# which is always radians. For converting to and from degrees. See code for
# usage demonstration.
DEGREE = tau/360

ZOOM_OFFSET = 8
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = None  # set to 'your_API_key'

# Max width or height of a single image grabbed from Google.
MAXSIZE = 640
# For cutting off the logos at the bottom of each of the grabbed images.  The
# logo height in pixels is assumed to be less than this amount.
LOGO_CUTOFF = 32


def latlon2pixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = lon
    my = log(tan((lat + tau/4)/2))
    res = 2**(zoom + ZOOM_OFFSET) / tau
    px = mx*res
    py = my*res
    return px, py

def pixels2latlon(px, py, zoom):
    res = 2**(zoom + ZOOM_OFFSET) / tau
    mx = px/res
    my = py/res
    lon = mx
    lat = 2*atan(exp(my)) - tau/4
    return lat, lon


def get_maps_image(NW_lat_long, SE_lat_long, zoom=18):

    ullat, ullon = NW_lat_long
    lrlat, lrlon = SE_lat_long

    # convert all these coordinates to pixels
    ulx, uly = latlon2pixels(ullat, ullon, zoom)
    lrx, lry = latlon2pixels(lrlat, lrlon, zoom)

    # calculate total pixel dimensions of final image
    dx, dy = lrx - ulx, uly - lry

    # calculate rows and columns
    cols, rows = ceil(dx/MAXSIZE), ceil(dy/MAXSIZE)

    # calculate pixel dimensions of each small image
    width = ceil(dx/cols)
    height = ceil(dy/rows)
    heightplus = height + LOGO_CUTOFF

    # assemble the image from stitched
    final = Image.new('RGB', (int(dx), int(dy)))
    for x in range(cols):
        for y in range(rows):
            dxn = width * (0.5 + x)
            dyn = height * (0.5 + y)
            latn, lonn = pixels2latlon(
                    ulx + dxn, uly - dyn - LOGO_CUTOFF/2, zoom)
            position = ','.join((str(latn/DEGREE), str(lonn/DEGREE)))
            print(x, y, position)
            urlparams = {
                    'center': position,
                    'zoom': str(zoom),
                    'size': '%dx%d' % (width, heightplus),
                    'maptype': 'roadmap',
                    'sensor': 'false',
                    'scale': 1
                }
            if GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY is not None:
                urlparams['key'] = GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY

            url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap'
            try:
                response = requests.get(url, params=urlparams)
                response.raise_for_status()
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(e)
                sys.exit(1)

            im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
            final.paste(im, (int(x*width), int(y*height)))

    return final

############################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # a neighbourhood in Lajeado, Brazil:
    NW_lat_long =  (1.351197*DEGREE, 103.715133*DEGREE)
    SE_lat_long = (1.230035*DEGREE, 103.933829*DEGREE)

    zoom = 13   # be careful not to get too many images!

    result = get_maps_image(NW_lat_long, SE_lat_long, zoom=zoom)
    result.show()
```

With this code, I am able to plot the map I wish to see. However, I am not sure where in this code I can add in lines and pins. I have the coordinates I need for this. I have a sample of the output I am looking for which I have generated using the gmplot module which only outputs HTML files. This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB26E.png) of the sample which uses a subset of my data. Note that I am able to plot all the routes but I am unable to open the HTML file as it is too large.

Sample list of route:

```
[[1.2973966666666668, 103.78098833333333], [1.297397, 103.780988], [1.2973966666666668, 103.78098833333333]]
```

Sample Pin:

```
[1.2973966666666668, 103.78098833333333]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.